# DataGridView crashing when sorting?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with multiple rows each representing one process. When one of these processes exits, the row is updated to reflect this by changing my PID column from the integer process id to the string `--`. If all of the processes are running and every cell in that column is a number, I can sort the PID column. If any of those processes have ended and even one cell contains `--` then when I try to sort on that column, the application fails. It highlights the `Application.Run(new MyForm());` line in Program.cs with an `ArgumentException` saying "Object must be of type Int32." The PID column is an unbound, DataGridViewTextBoxColumn who's SortMode is Automatic. How can I have it sort so that it doesn't crash and all rows that have a PID value of `--` are grouped together? I don't care if they're at the beginning or end of the sorted list.

Comment: Can you please post the code for your `Process` object and the code to databind the collection to the list?

Comment: It's not my Process object, it's `System.Diagnostics.Process` and as stated the column is Unbound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did it myself but i think you can use some kind of cell-formatter.
So you are able to store a value like `-1` for an exited process and this value will be automatically formatted into whatever you want like `--`

Maybe this can help you: [DataGridView.CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx)

I only do a quickread but i think thats exactly what i mean.

Comment: I am now extremely confused and irritated. I changed it from `--` to `-1` and it still gives me an exception, this time with this message: "Object must be of type String." FFS...

Comment: @CoreyOgburn me too =) maybe now its a different column? if all `PID`s are now from type `int` it should work

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I found that when I created the row I gave that column an int, but when I updated the row, I gave that column a string. Now it sorts properly because everything is an int.

Comment: It also crashes if one of the column's cells has a null value.
>Happened to me when i was trying to sort a column (unbounded table) was pulling data from a DataTable that was null-permissive. 
+ ! Fix was done in SQL table and queries: where I filled the null cells with "none".

Comment: While `CellFormatting` works for his specific use (as in, PIDs), in the general case this isn't a great solution because there are many cases where all integer (or double) values are valid and need to be sorted. Or the database case that @ArthurZennig was mentioning, it seems like a better way would be disable auto sorting, handle the column click yourself, and provide a custom IComparer (there is a `Sort` overload that takes in a custom comparer but unfortunately `DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic` doesn't allow you to provide one).

Answer (score 0):

You must fill same kind of data each column.
When your datatable's column have some string and some null it will be.
so;
If your data is null You must it "".
Hope explain it. Sorry for my english.